# Obtain all the attributes of a Snap Element

Tags: snap.svg

I am converting a large body of code from Raphael to Snap.

In Raphael, I was able to obtain an object containing most of the attributes of an Element by calling `Element.attr()`. Is there an equivalent in Snap?

Snap's `Element.attr()` only seems to return non-svg object properties.

Comment: I'm guessing you could loop through looking at element.note.attributes ?

Comment: Do you mean node? I need the attributes to be in the same form (and have the same names) as they have when used in `Element.attr({ name: value })`.

Comment: oops yes, I mean node. I assume attr just refers to the node.attributes, or are there some specific fiddly examples you've noticed where they are different as Snap does something extra to them ? One example maybe worth checking is what happens to certain attributes vs styling, as I think Snap may change some of these to styles. This is different to Raphael I 'think', but am not sure of.

Comment: That's a big (and incorrect, I think) assumption.

Comment: Depends what you mean there. To clarify, here is a quick example of what I mean, http://jsfiddle.net/oar760eu/ if you look at the console, and node.attributes and then look for the strokeWidth you will find it has been set as a style.

Comment: I am optimising some 3d drawing. In the Raphael version, drawing some things on an svg in an invisible div caused the text to end up in the wrong place (http://jsfiddle.net/nikkilocke/96k1ym0r/). Also, the main code calculates all the attributes on every animation, so I need to determine which attributes have changed, and only actually animate these. Plus I need to remember the correct attributes for invisible drawings, and only actually set them when the plane becomes visible. In Raphael, a call to attr() returned almost all the attributes that had earlier been set with attr. Snap doesn't.